# Subversion roadmap

Tags: svn

Recently there was a post [to the subversion dev mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201004.mbox/%3C4BB60D1E.9030202@collab.net%3E) suggesting a vision and roadmap for the future of Subversion. As a result, I'm posting this to elicit some suggestions and contributions from the users of Subversion. Any comments are welcome, and I shall feedback a synopsis with a link to this question to the dev mailing list.

On the post, several ideas were suggested as being "very nice to have" and are offered as the starting point of a future roadmap. These are:

- Obliterate
- Shelve/Checkpoint
- Repository-dictated Configuration
- Rename Tracking
- Improved Merging
- Improved Tree Conflict Handling
- Enterprise Authentication Mechanisms
- Forward History Searching
- Log Message Templates

---

So given all the above, what features in subversion, or missing from subversion, do you think could be improved or added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename tracking would be better than having to "delete" and "add". :)

Answer (score 1):

Some features that would save me time:

- Repository-wide "ignore" (for Thumbs.db, .DS_Store, and the like)
- An easier way to move folders from one repository to another, possibly with a "merge" function (easier than svndumpfilter).
- Local machine authentication for svnserve (not necessarily "enterprise" authentication, just authenticate with local user credentials).

Comment: now the migrate a folder (with history) is a cracking idea! The others are in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Compress transfers to /from server.
When doing a really big commit/checkout it can be insanely slow!